# How Do I get a webpage to display inside a tabbed page?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, webview, code-behind, tabbedpage

Is there a way to display webpages as tabbed page? The tabbed page has 2 tabs. One for about and one for contact, Is it possible to put the content of the tabbed page as just a url like "www.example.com/about" or "www.example.com/contact"? 
Currently I just have a button at the tabbed page that will open the browser. Code below:

```
  public AboutPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Title = "About";


        StackLayout contact = new StackLayout
        {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            Children = {
            new Label {
                HorizontalTextAlignment=TextAlignment.Center,
                Text = "contact here"
            }
            }
        };
        var browser = new WebView();
        var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();
        htmlSource.BaseUrl = "http://www.google.com";
        browser.Source = htmlSource;
        Button abtbutton = new Button
        {
            Text = "View about page"
        };
        abtbutton.Clicked += OnAboutBtnClicked;
        this.Children.Add(new ContentPage
        {
            Title = "About",
            Content = browser
        }
        );
        this.Children.Add(new ContentPage
        {
            Title = "Contact",
            Content = contact
        });
    }

    void OnAboutBtnClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        Device.OpenUri(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need two webViews.

```
var browser = new WebView();
browser.Source = new UrlWebViewSource { Url = "https://developer.xamarin.com/" };
this.Children.Add(new ContentPage
{
    Title = "About",
    Content = browser
}
);

var browser2 = new WebView();
browser2.Source = new UrlWebViewSource { Url = "https://stackoverflow.com/" };
this.Children.Add(new ContentPage
{
    Title = "Contact",
    Content = browser2
});
```

[image]